# Reloading page in cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an issue with cordova that i don't understand how to handle relatively to the opening of the same page more than once.

Suppose that i have two basic html files like this with cordova and jquery mobile support:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        ciao
    </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- cordova -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- jquery mobile -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/libs/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.css" />
    <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.js"></script>

    <!-- initialization files -->
    <script src="js/mainjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="index" data-role="page" data-fullscreen="true">
        <div data-role="content">
            /*...*/
            <a href="mappa.html">
                        <img src="img/map.png" />
            </a>
            /*...*/
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

mappa.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        mappa
    </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- cordova -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- jquery mobile -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/libs/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.css" />
    <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <section id="mappa" data-role="page" data-fullscreen="true">
        <div data-role="content">
            /* code*/
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i need to load data in the mappa.html file so i use an handler that i choose to load in the mainjs.js file included in the index like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log("deviceready");
$(document).on("pageshow","#mappa",function(){       //pageshow is thrown each time
                /*code*/
            });
});
```

If i use the code above each time i load the page all the handler start again and it's very user unfriendly in case of long operation like data downloading.

So i tried this handler

```
$(document).one("pageshow","#mappa",function(){ });
```

But the second time i enter in the mappa.html page simply is blank because the handler does't work 2 times.

So how can i maintain the page loaded?

EDIT: In this specific case i need to load a map and with this code

```
$(document).on("pageshow","#mappa",function(){       //pageshow is thrown each time
    console.log("dentro script"); 
    //setting div height
    $("#map_canvas").height( $(window).height() - $("div[data-role='header']").height() - 32 );

    //since page show is thrown each time i use a session storage variable
    //so i make the init map only one time
    if( !sessionStorage.mapinit ) {
        console.log("----------mapinit is not set");
        sessionStorage.mapinit=1;
        console.log("----------mapinit=1");
        // Initialize the map plugin
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
        var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(mapDiv);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        var pisaCenter = new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(43.723072, 10.396585);
        map.setCenter(pisaCenter);
        map.setZoom(13);
        map.one(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapInit);
    } else {
        console.log("----------map already set");
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
        var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(mapDiv);
    }  
});
```

and it works fine thanks to

```
map.one(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapInit);
```

that execute the onMapInit function only once.

But in a case like this one

```
<body>
<script>
    $.support.cors=true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $.getJSON('http://.../prestazioni.php?prestazioni=tutto&callback=?',function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i, dat){
            $("#listview").append('<li>'+dat.rep+'</li>');
        });
        $('#listview').listview('refresh');
    });
</script>
</body>
```

it's absurd that i need to download data every time i open the page

Comment: Post the code you run on `pageshow`.

Comment: You want to load the map one time only?

Comment: I want to know how can i load each page only one time not only the map.

Comment: `pageshow` fires whenever you visit a page, so if you want to run code one time only, use either `pagecreate` event or `.one("pageshow"` to run code one time when page is shown. `.one` not `.on`.

Comment: Either if i use pageshow or pagecreate with the .one() handler the page is blank the second time i load it

Comment: You need to switch to a multipage template which stores everything in the Dom so your pages dont refresh unless you need to refresh them. You can try (data-dom-cache="true") for now to see if that will help. --- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/pages/

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is related to jquery mobile and how it load pages.

So in my case i use multiple html files and jquery does't cache the open pages; this behavoour can be overwritten adding data-dom-cache="true" at the page like this

```
<section id="prestazioni" data-role="page" data-fullscreen="true" data-dom-cache="true">
```

This works very well. The page remains loaded but it's also possible to modify it using the handler.

There is also an easy route that simply consist in the creation of a single html files with multiple pages. in this case the DOM is always the same and the pages are all cached.